# Footer always on bottom with fixed header/height

Tags: html, css

Ok, so I'm trying to figure out how to get this worked out:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="container></div>
    <div id="footer></div>
</div>
```

The header should have a `position: fixed` (always on top of the screen) but the container-div should start below the fixed header div, not beneath it.

The footer should always be on the bottom of the page. Not fixed.

Is there an easy quick way to solve this (CSS)? I can get it 'almost' to work, but when I try to position the container-div below (instead of beneath) the header, the whole page messes up.

This is what I mean:
http://jsfiddle.net/jskjvpkv/1/

I found my own solution, see my answer.

Comment: You could add `margin-top` to the container div equal to the header's height

Comment: Then the page messes up. I'll make a JSFiddle, hold on

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what your problem is:

If it is that the header isn't at the top try this in it's CSS:

```
top: auto;
bottom: 100%;
```

Footer should be:

```
position: static;
top: 100%;
bottom: auto;
```

If you are having the header overlay other elements you should add some padding:

```
padding-bottom: 10px;
```

or however big your header is.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `top: 0px` to your `header` div and then assign `margin-top` to your `container` div which is equal to the height of the fixed `header`, like the following CSS:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
#wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
#header {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  height: 60px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0px;
}
#container {
  margin-top: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 3.75em;
  background: #c00;
  height: 1000px;
}
#footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3.75em;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header"></div>
  <div id="container">Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here.</div>
  <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jskjvpkv/6/)**.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This works, but when you decrease the height from the container to like 50px, you have to scroll to see the footer. You got a fix for that? Also the code applied in the browser works in Firefox but not in Chrome.

Comment: The code is working perfectly fine on Chrome since I used Chrome myself while writing it. Moreover, as far as the footer is concerned, it's sticking to the bottom of the page because you're using `bottom: 0`. You can remove that and the footer will appear right after the container regardless of the height of the container, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/jskjvpkv/11/

Answer (score 0):

You can make it like this

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
#wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
#header {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  height: 60px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
#container {
  position: relative;
  top: 60px;
  background: #c00;
  min-height: calc(100% - 60px);
}
#footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3.75em;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header"></div>
  <div id="container"></div>
  <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution which worked best for me:

```css
html,
body {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 height:100%;
}
#wrapper {
 min-height:100%;
 position:relative;
}
#header {
 background:#ededed;
 padding:10px;
}
#content {
 padding-bottom:100px;
}
#footer {
 background:#ffab62;
 width:100%;
 height:100px;
 position:absolute;
 bottom:0;
 left:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```